# Parse email addresses for "from" and "to" fields in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, email

In an email, it looks like a "from" or "to" field can contain one or more addresses, each address can be like `"john@test.com"` or `"John D Jr <john@test.com>"`

So a "from" field can look like any of the following:

```
"a@a.com"

"a@a.com, Bob Blue <b@b.com>"

"Abe Allen <a@a.com>, b@b.com"

"Abe Allen <a@a.com>, Bob Blue <b@b.com>"

"Abe Allen <a@a.com>, Bob Blue <b@b.com>, c@c.com"
```

and so on.

I want to parse these fields, extracting each address' email if it's valid, and the name if it's present. Since I'm not familiar with the email standard, I may be missing some cases of what address fields can look like. Is there a Ruby library that can do this?

Comment: Parsing and validating email addresses is not a trivial task. The range of formats is huge, and even if an address is valid, it's easily possible that it's bogus and not a deliverable address. See "[I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx)" for an interesting article about the subject. Also [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) and [the SMTP RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322) itself.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there's a gem for this; it's called **[mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail)**.

```
require 'mail'

addresses = []
raw_addresses = Mail::AddressList.new("Abe Allen <a@a.com>, Bob Blue <b@b.com>, c@c.com")

raw_addresses.addresses.each do |a|  
  address = {}

  address[:address] = a.address
  address[:name]    = a.display_name if a.display_name.present?

  addresses << address      
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for my use case. Btw, I think you meant to do "raw_addresses.addresses.each"?

Comment: Worth noting that the `mail` gem is included indirectly by Rails, so is already available if you're developing a Rails-based app.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data follows the examples you gave, this should work:

```
def extract_emails(string)
  string.split(', ').map do |user_string|
    if user_string.include? '<'
      user_string =~ /^([^<]*)<([^>]*)>$/
      {user: $1.strip, email: $2}
    else
      {user: nil, email: user_string}
    end
  end
end

extract_emails "a@a.com"                                          
# => [{:user=>nil, :email=>"a@a.com"}]

extract_emails "a@a.com, Bob Blue <b@b.com>"                      
# => [{:user=>nil, :email=>"a@a.com"}, {:user=>"Bob Blue", :email=>"b@b.com"}]

extract_emails "Abe Allen <a@a.com>, b@b.com"                     
# => [{:user=>"Abe Allen", :email=>"a@a.com"}, {:user=>nil, :email=>"b@b.com"}]

extract_emails "Abe Allen <a@a.com>, Bob Blue <b@b.com>"          
# => [{:user=>"Abe Allen", :email=>"a@a.com"}, {:user=>"Bob Blue", :email=>"b@b.com"}]

extract_emails "Abe Allen <a@a.com>, Bob Blue <b@b.com>, c@c.com" 
# => [{:user=>"Abe Allen", :email=>"a@a.com"}, {:user=>"Bob Blue", :email=>"b@b.com"}, {:user=>nil, :email=>"c@c.com"}]
```

Comment: OP said "I'm not familiar with the email standard, I may be missing some cases of what address fields can look like."...

Comment: Sure, but unless his emails or user names include "<" and ">", this will work fine with all data. If they can include these, then he'll basically have to write a parser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a library, but if you are trying to get a list of the emails you could do the following yourself. (Long winded on purpose)

```
@a = "Abe Allen <a@a.com>, Bob Blue <b@b.com>, c@c.com"
b = @a.split(',') #=> ["Abe Allen <a@a.com>", " Bob Blue <b@b.com>", " c@c.com"] 
c = b.collect{|x| x[/<(.*?)>|^([^<>]*)$/]} #=> ["<a@a.com>", "<b@b.com>", " c@c.com"] 
d = c.gsub(/[<>]/,'') #=> ["a@a.com", "b@b.com", " c@c.com"]
```

If you want to match their names and email addresses, you will need something else.

Also, this won't work if there are '<' or '>' in the email address, but that's pretty uncommon.