# Regexp to find hostname and subdomain from email address

Tags: regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse email addresses for “from” and “to” fields in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187220/parse-email-addresses-for-from-and-to-fields-in-ruby)

Given an email address of the form `root@host.sub.domain.com`, what is the regular expression to get the hostname and the subdomain as two individual variables? I mean `$1='host'`and `$2='sub'`?

You help is greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT** I should say I'm asking about a *regular expression* to do this, no Ruby code. This is to be used in a postfix configuration file, so I need a regexp. I mistakenly talked about Ruby earlier. My fault, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, I'd try parsing the URL first: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse

Comment: @andreas-h: Then something like `^(?:.*?)@(.*?)\.(.*?)\.(?:.*?)\.(?:.*?)$` will capture all of the groups you need.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. No Ruby involved here; it's for a Postfix config file.

Comment: @Blender Thanks! If that were an answer I'd select it as correct ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-greedy groups are your friend. They match just what you need:

```
^(?:.*?)@(.*?)\.(.*?)\.(?:.*?)\.(?:.*?)$
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow, Postfix doesn't like this, though. I use `/^(?:.*?)@(.*?)\.(.*?)\.(?:.*?)\.(?:.*?)$/ admin+${1}_${2}@mydomain.net`, and this results in an error *Invalid preceding regular expression*. I tested your answer in some online checker, though, and it works. Do you have an idea what might cause the problem?

Comment: okay, got it working. I need to tell postfix it's a PCRE.