# How do I write this regex in ruby? (parsing Gmail API fields)

Tags: ruby, regex, email-parsing

I have 3 types of strings I need to parse:

```
"John Smith <jsmith@gmail.com>"

"\"jsmith@gmail.com\" <jsmith@gmail.com>, \"bob@gmail.com\" <bob@gmail.com>"

"\"yo@gmail.com\" <yo@gmail.com>, John Smith <jsmith@gmial.com>"
```

I need a hash of each, that looks like:

```
{ 'John Smith' => 'jsmith@gmail.com' } # for the first one

{ 'jsmith@gmail.com' => 'jsmith@gmail.com', 'bob@gmail.com' => 'bob@gmail.com' } # for the second one

{ 'yo@gmail.com' => 'yo@gmail.com', 'John Smith' => 'jsmith@gmail.com' } # for the third one
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hash[email_string.scan(/"(.*?)" <(.*?)>/)] tried this but it assumes the first part is always surrounded by \" but when gmail returns a name, there's nothing surrounding it

Comment: Why not use [the gmail gem](https://github.com/gmailgem/gmail) or similar where the parsing is done for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) gem to parse.

```
emails = "\"jsmith@gmail.com\" <jsmith@gmail.com>, \"bob@gmail.com\" <bob@gmail.com>, \"Bobby\" <bobby@gmail.com>"

raw_addresses = Mail::AddressList.new(emails)

result = raw_addresses.addresses.map {|a| {name: a.name, email: a.address}}
```

The same thread: [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187220/parse-email-addresses-for-from-and-to-fields-in-ruby)

Comment: I'd do the same. While you can do regexps, going with a stable gem like mail normally means less maintenance down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Regexp, no gem required...

It probably requires some testing, but it seems okay.

```
str = "yo0@gmail.com; yo1@gmail.com, \"yo2@gmail.com\" <yo@gmail.com>, John Smith <jsmith@gmial.com>"

str.split(/[\s]*[,;][\s]*/).each.with_object({}) {|addr, hash| a = addr.match(/[\"]?([^\"\<]*)[\"]?[\s]*\<([\w@\w\.]+)\>/) ; a ? hash[a[1].strip] = a[2]: hash[addr] = addr}

# => {"yo0@gmail.com"=>"yo0@gmail.com", "yo1@gmail.com"=>"yo1@gmail.com",
#     "yo2@gmail.com"=>"yo@gmail.com", "John Smith"=>"jsmith@gmial.com"}
```

Please notice that the hash will NOT hold two identical keys - so **using a Hash might result in loss of data!**

consider the following cases:

1. One person with two email addresses.
2. Two people who share the same name but not the same email address.

**Both cases result in lost data when using a Hash, as opposed to using an Array.** Both Array of arrays and an Array of hashes would work well.

Observe:

```
str = "John Smith <email1@gmail.com>, John Smith <another_address@gmail.com>"

str.split(/[\s]*[,;][\s]*/).each.with_object({}) {|addr, hash| a = addr.match(/[\"]?([^\"\<]*)[\"]?[\s]*\<([\w@\w\.]+)\>/) ; a ? hash[a[1].strip] = a[2]: hash[addr] = addr}

#  => {"John Smith"=>"another_address@gmail.com"}
# Only ONE email extracted.

str.split(/[\s]*[,;][\s]*/).each.with_object([]) {|addr, arry| a = addr.match(/[\"]?([^\"\<]*)[\"]?[\s]*\<([\w@\w\.]+)\>/) ; a ? arry << [ a[1].strip, a[2] ]: [ addr, addr ]}

#  => [["John Smith", "email1@gmail.com"], ["John Smith", "another_address@gmail.com"]] 
# Both addresses extracted.

str.split(/[\s]*[,;][\s]*/).each.with_object([]) {|addr, arry| a = addr.match(/[\"]?([^\"\<]*)[\"]?[\s]*\<([\w@\w\.]+)\>/) ; a ? arry << {name: a[1].strip, email: a[2] }: {email: addr} }

# => [{:name=>"John Smith", :email=>"email1@gmail.com"}, {:name=>"John Smith", :email=>"another_address@gmail.com"}] 
# Both addresses extracted.
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
myHash = {}
str = "\"vishal@sendsonar.com\" <vishal@sendsonar.com>, Michael Makarov <michael@sendsonar.com>"
str.strip.split(',').map{|x| x.strip}.each do |contact|
  parts = contact.scan(/"{0,1}(.*?)"{0,1} <(.*?)>/)
  myHash[parts[0][0]] = parts[0][1]
end
```